# What ways are there to implement variable text in Docusaurus

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

In moving our documentation site to Docusaurus. Previously, our files were in Dita XML and we used conref's to implement variable text for things like version numbers, product names, etc.

I'm new to React and MDX, but I stumbled on a way to do this, but I'm sure it is kind of hackey and probably not the best implementation. I created a small React component for each word/phrase we wanted to use. I can see these being in a file separately and included as needed. If someone could help to understand if there is a better way or what limitations there would be with this method, that would be great! I'm just now trying to learn React.

This is a sample I wrote:

```
export const Version = () => (
  '4.0'
);

export const Our_company = () => (
   'Spacely Sprockets'
);

export const Our_competitor = () => (
   'Cogswell Cogs'
)

## Announcement

Here at <Our_company/> we are pleased to announce version <Version/> of our product that competes directly with <Our_competitor/> .
```

Answer (score 0):

**Implement variable text in Docusaurus**

- Create an MDX file, such as Variables.mdx, with variable components
  defined using React props.
- Use the variable components in your    documentation files by
  wrapping the desired text with the component    tags.
- Render the MDX content in your Docusaurus pages, importing the
  Variables.mdx file and placing  in your page.
- Configure    Docusaurus to support MDX files, including installing
  necessary    packages and updating your configuration.

Comment: So is that similar to my sample, or something different?

Comment: yes it is similar to your  solution

Comment: Do you have a sample you could share?